# How can I create text with a "button" look on Stack Exchange sites?

Tags: discussion, markdown, information-display

How can I do this on Stack Exchange sites?

> [image]

The *Alt & D*. I don't know what keyword to search for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

<kbd>Like this?</kbd>

```
<kbd>Like this?</kbd>
```

Note that if you ever want to see the markdown source of a post, you can just click "edit" and see the raw markdown code.

Comment: Note that this markup is for **user input**. Do not use it excessively, and certainly do not use it just to make things look like buttons.

Comment: @animuson But... [kbd castles](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/71407/180276) and [pyramids](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/114743/180276)... :P

Comment: Didn't thought that kind of "edit" trick. anyway, thanks! :)